# How to give condition for Contact Form Only For Registered Customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, contact-form, registry

Below is my Contact Form Email id Box :

```
<div class="field">
                    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How can i give condition here like registered customer only submit enquiry form. this condition should check from my customer Database, if email id is not registered enforced to signup.

**I am getting so many spam emails every day.**

Comment: Amasty do a free extension that lets you add google recaptcha to your contact form https://amasty.com/magento-google-invisible-captcha.html

Answer (score 1):

You can put log in condition like below code. i was use this condition if user is logged in then show this field else another

```
<?php                           
                            //Get the customer session and check if the customer is logged in
                            if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                            // Get the customer object from customer session
                            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

                        ?>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">

                            <div class="field col-xs-6">
                                <label for="name" class="formlabel"> Full Name <span class="required">*</span> </label> 
                                <input class="textfield" type="text" value="<?php echo $customer->getName(); ?>"  name="fname" id="fname" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="field col-xs-6">
                                <label class="formlabel"> Email <span class="required">*</span> </label> 
                                <input class="textfield" type="email" value="<?php echo $customer->getEmail(); ?>" name="email" id="email" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>

                        <?php } 
                        else {
                        ?>

                        <div class="col-xs-12">

                            <div class="field col-xs-6">
                                <label for="name" class="formlabel"> Full Name <span class="required">*</span> </label> 
                                <input class="textfield" type="text"  data-required="true" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="field col-xs-6">
                                <label class="formlabel"> Email <span class="required">*</span> </label> 
                                <input class="textfield"  data-required="true" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Please Enter Email Address" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>

                        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: hi Wajahat, this is my condition for my FORM -> https://justpaste.it/1jo3v   Its not working... could you kindly help me.

Comment: send me your email

Comment: zus710@gmail.com

Comment: Let me know when you send the code...

Comment: i sent you code file open and search (Product Enquiry) in that form i'm using these condition you can understand easily.. and this code is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an observer to check if you customer is logged in to display contact us form

Create a module and in config.xml file define your observer

**config.xml**

```
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_index>
            <observers>
                <contact_check_customer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Modulename_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkCustomer</method>
                </contact_check_customer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_index>                                    
  </events>
```

In your Observer File

**Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer
{

    public function checkCustomer(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
            $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
            $controllerAction->getResponse()
                    ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to observer,  How can i use your above code.

Comment: refer to this example https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/12/making-use-of-observers-in-magento/